# Trying to understand why a networking packet route is being chosen

Tags: networking, laptop, routing

I'm here to looking an explanation regarding network route issue.

I have two laptops A and B, laptop A connect to public network while laptop B connect to laptop A via the laptop A hotspot. Thus, laptop B -`192.168.137.128` is able communicate to public network also.

Laptop A have three network adapters:

1. wireless LAN adapters - `192.168.1.6`(physical)
2. vmware virtual network adapter - `192.168.88.1`(created by vmware)
3. wireless LAN virtual adapter - `192.168.137.1` (created by Laptop A hotspot)

Also, I have turned off my firewall.

Here's my laptop A route table (just a part)

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.6     50 // <--- physical interface WIFI
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.88.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.88.1    291 // <--- virtual interface VMnet8
     192.168.88.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.88.1    291 // <--- virtual interface VMnet8
    192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    306 // <--- virtual wireless interface
    192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    306 // <--- virtual wireless interface
```

Here's my laptop B route table

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.137.1      UGSc           en0       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#4             UCS            en0      !
192.168.137        link#4             UCS            en0      !
192.168.137.1/32   link#4             UCS            en0      !
192.168.137.1      2:bb:60:21:8c:2a   UHLWIir        en0   1128
192.168.137.102/32 link#4             UCS            en0      !
192.168.137.255    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI         en0      !
```

For my understanding, every IP packet based on table above to decide which interface is used to outgoing.

Laptop A ping to ip `192.168.88.134` will using network interface `192.168.88.1` to send out package (Is working).

[image]

Laptop B communicate with public network by using network interface `192.168.1.6` (Is working)

[image]

However, why laptop B cannot ping `192.168.88.134` which inside laptop A. The network interface `192.168.88.1` didn't receive any package. (indicated by wireshark capture)

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why this occur, based on my understanding, when laptop A accept the IP packet from laptop B, it should be send out by 192.168.88.1 interface due to route table configure above.
Am I misunderstanding? Can someone point out where my wrong?

Comment: Your setup is a bit complicated and puzzle me. You tell B has the address 168.192.1.6, but go through A to reach Internet. However the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet is nowhere in the routing table of A. How did B get its address ? Surely not from A. Then there are surely something missing in your explanations. If B runs Windows, `route print` should give valuable information (`ip route` if Linux).

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer Thank for comment, I had been edit a bit to indicate the IP address of each interface and show route table in laptop B. A is the gateway of B, thus when B trying to reach internet, the packet of B is then pass by using address 192.168.1.6

Comment: Perhaps unrelated but I note you are using a VMWare NAT adapter. Have you configured NAT to allow the traffic? does changing it to bridged have any impact?

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank for comment. In fact, the things i confuse her is not the VMware network configuration, my confusing is why A didn't send out the packet to "192.168.88.1 interface". BTW, I had been allow NAT traffic for vmware (network inside the VM host is work properly), if i changing it to bridge, it become a host inside my LAN, i can access directly by another host which inside LAN.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that 192.168.88.134 has not its route table configured to make this node knowns B is reachable through A. In enterprise networks, we use routing protocols to make nodes exchange their routes. For smaller networks, we can setup fixed routes on any router (including 192.168.88.134 or its default gateway). If not possible, network address translation (NAT) on A can make the B IP stream transformed to an IP stream which seems to come from A. The answers addressed to A are then transformed back and sent to B.

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer, but I don't really understand about "192.168.88.134 has not its route table configured to make this node knowns B is reachable through A". The packet from B (icmp to 192.168.88.134) had been arrived A (3rd image show above), and A has associated route "192.168.88.0/24 ->192.168.88.1", it suppose to send out the packet to 192.168.88.1 network interface right ?

Comment: Laptop B is 192.168.137.128. Then if the destination has only a route for 192.168.88.0/24, it will receive packets but won’t be able to reply. Could you print the destination route table ? And try a ping from 192.168.88.134 with wireshark activated.